# how to make ConstraintLayout to follow my progress in ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I know that there is questions like this on this site but can't apply their solutions on my problem, or simply do not know how. I am trying to make my ConstraintLayout that is part of my layout to be placed on end of my progress,like this:

[image]

but in my case it is always on center of progressbar

my xml:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:progress="60"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goal_name_TV" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tv_content_rounded"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/goal_name_TV">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bullet_IMG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bulet_blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/marker_value"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/marker_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="985"
            android:textColor="@color/background"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bullet_IMG"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my java:

```
 binding.seekBar2.setProgress((int) modelClass.getPercentage());
        binding.markerValue.setText(binding.seekBar2.getProgress()+"%");
        int position = (((binding.seekBar2.getRight() - binding.seekBar2.getLeft()/binding.seekBar2.getMax()) * binding.seekBar2.getProgress())+ binding.seekBar2.getLeft());
        binding.thumb.setTranslationX((float) ((double)position - (binding.thumb.getWidth()/2)));
```

also i tried to make custom progrssbar but in vain